# Trying to post the results of 2 select queries on my php page

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to echo out both these select queries within a PHP page, when ran, only the first query is echo'ing out.

Below is the PHP containing the two SELECT statements:

```
<?php
session_start();
$getid =  $_SESSION['parentid'];
$username = $_SESSION["parentlogin"];
$minderID = $_SESSION["minderid"];
include ("secure/connect.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM children_info";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die (mysqli_error($conn));

include ("secure/connect.php"); 
$messages = "SELECT * FROM privatemessagePA";
$printmessages = mysqli_query($conn, $messages) or die (mysqli_error($conn));
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Here is the code I am using to try and display the results of the two SELECT queries:

```
<?php
include ("secure/connect.php");
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)> 0 ){
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
$addchild = $row["name"]; 
$age =$row["age"];
echo "<div>
<p></p>
<p><h4><b>Name: </b>$addchild</h4></p>                       
<p><b>Age: </b>$age</p>
</div>";                
}     
}  
?> 

<?php
include ("secure/connect.php");
if 
(mysqli_num_rows($messages)> 0 ){
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($messages)){ 
$name = $row ["name"];
$childname1 = $row ["childname"];
$message1 = $row ["message"];             
echo "<div>    
<img src=img/newmsg.png>
<p><h3><b>Message Information</h3></p>
<p><b>Parent Name: </b>$name</p>
<p><b>Child's Name:</b>$childname1</p>
<p><b>Message:</b>$message1</p>    
</div>";                
}     
}  
?>
```

Would anyone have any ideas why the second query is not echo'ing out?

Comment: Please clarify what do you want?

Comment: Please show us the part of the code that is doing the actual printing. This just shows how you fetch it.

Comment: You shouldn't include twice the same file (connect.php). Try to remove the second inclusion and run again. I think should work.